# send email with attachment from mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, smtp

1)How to retrieve value of attachment from mysql database to send email with the attachment? (Uploaded attachment to database part is done.)

2)Is there must have a stored physical location file in server to keep the attachment files?

3)Below code i tried in my local pc.It can works by storing this testing.pdf file in my images folder.Is there another way to send email with attachment instead of using the explicit file path?

mailmssg.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Server.MapPath("Images/testing.pdf")))

Sorry been asking so many question as I am new in this issue and hope you guys can help~ Thanks in advance!

Comment: the attachments has to be stored , it wont pop out of thin air can it?

Comment: User CRON process for that.